# How do l prompt the end-user to select/check mandatory radio buttons when they haven't been selected or checked?

Tags: javascript

I want to prompt the end-user to select/check mandatory radio buttons that haven’t been selected before submitting an online form.

Currently when I click the submit button, it highlights the empty fields but bypasses the mandatory unchecked radio buttons and submits the form once the empty fields have been filled. Is there a way to make sure that the user checks/selects the mandatory radio buttons before submitting the form? See code snippet below:

```
<form name="onlinepensionform" action=" submit " onsubmit="return checkforblank()" method="post">
1.  Do you require a Centrelink or Veterans' Affairs Schedule?
               <input type="radio" name="RequiresCentrelinkOrVeteransAffairSchedule"  value="Yes">
                     <label for="RequiresCentrelinkOrVeteransAffairSchedule">Yes</label>
               <input type="radio" name="RequiresCentrelinkOrVeteransAffairSchedule"  value="No">
                     <label for="RequiresCentrelinkOrVeteransAffairSchedule">No</label>

2.   Please confirm your identity using one of the below Government issued identification.
               <label for="IdentityType">Australian driver's licence number:</label>  <input name="IdentityValue" type="text"  id="IdentityValue" value="" />
        <label for="IdentityType">State of Issue:</label>   <input name="IdentityValue" type="text"  id="IdentityValue" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
```

Comment: I feel like we need some more information here. Are you just talking about form validation?

Comment: with html5, you can use required attribute in radio button, which forces user to select something before submit

Comment: @MattSpinks I've added the code for clarification purposes. Is there a way of creating a js if statement to trigger an alert if the mandatory form fields are not selected/checked?

Comment: @YogeshKumarGupta If it was just an ordinary empty field that would be easy to implement. Considering that (looking at the code) question 1 is a yes or no answer..I can't just add the required attribute because I do not know which option the end user is going to choose. Is there a way to trigger an alert if neither field is selected and further more for question two, once an end user selects an identity option is there a way to make the radio button selected mandatory therefore prompting the member to both select the radio button and fill in the empty field associated with the selection?

Comment: Check the modified fiddle

Comment: @YogeshKumarGupta Thanks you for your help!!!

Comment: Cn you accept the answer if it resolved your issue

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/ugeshgupta000/8kdn9L9e/2/

```
    <form name="onlinepensionform" action="submit" method="post">

    <div>
    <p>1.  Do you require a Centrelink or Veterans' Affairs Schedule?</p>
    <input type="radio" required name="RequiresCentrelinkOrVeteransAffairSchedule"  value="Yes">
    <label for="RequiresCentrelinkOrVeteransAffairSchedule">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" required name="RequiresCentrelinkOrVeteransAffairSchedule"  value="No">
    <label for="RequiresCentrelinkOrVeteransAffairSchedule">No</label>
    </div>

    <div class="additionalInfo">
      <p>2. Please confirm your identity using one of the below Government issued identification.</p>
      <label for="IdentityValue">Australian driver's licence number:</label>
      <input name="IdentityValue" type="text"  id="IdentityValue" value="" required />
      <br />
      <label for="IdentityType">State of Issue:</label>
      <input name="IdentityType" type="text"  id="IdentityType" value="" required />
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit Form">
    </div>                   
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('input[name="RequiresCentrelinkOrVeteransAffairSchedule"]').change(function(){
   var val = $(this).val();
   if(val=='Yes') {
      $('.additionalInfo').find('input').attr('required','required');
      $('.additionalInfo').show();
   } else if(val=='No'){
      $('.additionalInfo').find('input').removeAttr('required');
      $('.additionalInfo').hide();
   }
});
```